# Model is not updated with ajax post in asp.net mvc?

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, forms

I am using asp.net mvc application.
In my view page i have textbox like below code:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Id, new { @class = "form-control", @readonly = "readonly" })
```

Also, in form submit ajax post,

```
$('#btnSubmit').click(function(e)
    {
        $.ajax({
            url: '/button/Button',
            type: 'POST',
            data: {Id:1},
           });
    });
```

My controller:

```
 MasterM empcode = new MasterM();

        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult Button()
        {

            var empcode = new MasterM();

            return View(empcode);
         }

        [HttpPost]
        public  ActionResult Button(MasterM model)
        {
            ModelState.Clear();
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return View(model);
            }
            return View(model);
        }
```

after this form submit the value of the text box should change to new value (1). How can i achieve this in controller section itself.
I know in ajax success we can manually update the element value but i want to achieve this in controller section and update model with new values.

Comment: why are sending ajax call, just do normal form post

Comment: Your model is being updated in the controller (the value of `Id` is `1` is the POST method). If you want to update the textbox, then use javascript, or update the DOM with the view you have returned in the success callback

Comment: No i need ajax call for some other purpose

Comment: @StephenMuecke, here for sample i have given 1 directly but in real case it will change by some other actions

Comment: There is no point using ajax if you going to return the whole view!

Comment: Do you have a method called ButtonFeatures?

Comment: no Vijay, its a button only now i changed thanks

Comment: If you need ajax then return the value which will reflect the new value in text box and update it using javascript. Just returning view to a ajax call will not update the view. It will be discarded unless you do something in javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are Posting your are sending only a Single Id and not the Entire Model , 
So basically this

```
public  ActionResult Button(MasterM model) will be empty
```

and since you are returning back the empty set the text box will not be updated.

There are 2 things you can do here :
1) Modify the Receiving type to

```
 Public  ActionResult Button(int Id)
    {
    MasterM model = new MasterM();
    model.Id = Id;
     if (!ModelState.IsValid)
                {
                    return View(model);
                }
                return View(model);
    }
```

2) If you want to retain Model as your Param in Controller 
you need to serialize the Data in Jquery and post it .